# Postgres cursors behaviour

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I am trying to understand a PostgreSQL behaviour.
In my application I am using a Postgres (AWS Aurora to be precise) database through ODBC.

I am not specifying "with hold" on the cursors used but I see in the logs that most of them are 'idle in transaction', although there is no transaction, there is just a 'select'. The statements look like:

```
RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_05A0C768;SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_05A0C768;declare "SQL_CUR05A0E3F8" cursor with hold for select u_selskap,u_kodetyp,u_tekst from u_hrm.u_stilltyp where u_selskap=50 and u_kodetyp='T';fetch 100 in "SQL_CUR05A0E3F8"
```

In PgAdmin we can see how the statements are displayed.

[image: PgAdmin screenshot]

The idling cursors seem to keep locks on the database hence subsequent queries cannot be run.
I am not able to understand why these cursors are in a transaction and which part of the chain is introducing the 'with hold' as the default creation mode is 'without hold'(as seen here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-declare.html).

Can it be a PostgreSQL ODBC issue?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Indeed it's unclear even for me. I will try to explain:
1. I am creating the cursors in the C code with no option hence they should be "without hold" as it is seen in the documentation. So my guess is that ODBC adds that.
2. Postgres is in autocommit mode so I was expecting that this will close the cursor when is read. Probably it should be read completely? I am not sure that I read all the rows.

Comment: Reading the ODBC driver source, it looks like `SQLExecute` and `SQLExecDirect` always create a `WITH HOLD` cursor. I guess you have to explicitly close the statement to get rid of it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe:  I partially fixed the problem by reading the ODBC source. Thre is an obscure reference to odbc.ini parameter DECLARE_FETCH. If set on 0 (aka don't use) the behaviour of the cursors is the expected one. Still the locks remain.

Comment: Locks are always held until the end of the transaction. Locks are **never** held beyond the end of the transaction.